# ORM - pattern model, object and storage

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

I am using an ORM for the class User for instance. (SQLAlchemy & python)
But I don't like to see how all instances of the class User can interact so easily with the database, making it difficult to enforce a better software quality.

Do you recommend to implement for each mapped class: a model class + an object class (used everywhere in the code, hiding the db) + storage class (to transform model into object and object into model with validation)?

Comment: How many layers of abstraction you need depends greatly on the actual application you are building and its specific requirements.

Comment: Are there recommended patterns to abstract the heavy model classes of  ORMs?

Comment: The recommended pattern is to evaluate your particular software's specific requirements, and then decide how much abstraction you need.  You should also read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/102937)